# how to do deal with svn update when files are skipped?

Tags: svn

I had postponed conflicts in svn update.  But now I get the following:
I need to **check files in** and after I made changes and I need to **keep some of the files that are in svn**, determined after the fact.

Not sure how to go about that?

```
hi-de-ho:~/work/ho_volumizer$ svn update
Skipped 'src/GUI/rate_child_page.ui'
Skipped 'src/GUI/rate_child_page.cpp'

Fetching external item into 'src/libGuidance'

At revision 16527.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve the conflicts.  You can get back into interactive conflict resolution by running `svn resolve`.  Once the conflicts are resolved properly you can run `svn update`.

Reading the section in the [SVN Book on resolving conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) may be helpful as well.